# sort array low to high

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
$pics = array("0"=>"pic-1", "1"=>"pic-2", "2"=>"pic-3", "3"=>"pic-4",  "4"=>"pic-5");
```

and I would like to sort it from low to high, but from a defined starting point that is not 0, and then add the remaining values at the end, also from low to high.

So for example having key 2 as the starting point I would like to end with

```
$pics = array("2"=>"pic-3", "3"=>"pic-4", "4"=>"pic-5", "0"=>"pic-1",  "1"=>"pic-2");
```

Can someone explain to me how this can be done?

Comment: use `usort()` to provide your own sorting functionality, or just sort in plain ascending order, then use splice operations to chop things up in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out this, please check it:

```
<?php
//
// $start: starting position to sort in [0, count($xarr) - 1].
//
function sortArrayFromPosition($xarr, $start)
{
//
  if($start < 0)
  {
    return $xarr;
  }
  elseif($start >= count($xarr))
  {
    return $xarr;
  }
  //
  // sort the ending elements:
  //
  $ends = array_slice($xarr, $start, null, true);
  asort($ends);
  //
  // append beginning elements:
  //
  $i = 0;
  foreach($xarr as $key => $value)
  {
    if($i > $start)
    {
        $break;
    }
    $ends[$key] = $value;
    $i++;
  }
  return $ends;
}

//
// main tests:
//
//$pics = array("0"=>"pic-1", "1"=>"pic-2", "2"=>"pic-3", "3"=>"pic-4", "4"=>"pic-5");
$pics0 = array("0"=>"pic-1", "1"=>"pic-5", "2"=>"pic-3", "3"=>"pic-2", "4"=>"pic-4");
//
$start = 2;
$pics = sortArrayFromPosition($pics0, $start);
//
echo "<pre>";
print_r($pics);
echo "</pre>";

//
$start = 4;
$pics = sortArrayFromPosition($pics0, $start);
//
echo "<pre>";
print_r($pics);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```